# How to use onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I override the **`onSaveInstanceState`** function below

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I have a question. What's problem if I **omit** the `**super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)**`, so the function will be like this

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I hope you can explain me as detailed as better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit doing that (calling the supper implementation), then you'll have to figure out a way of saving you're data (Which will include a mechanism that will allow to check if a state was saved).

The `super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle);` method writes the bundle and all it contains in related object, that the activity (of fragment) can access in it's `onCreate(Bundle)` method.
The're is some info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

But note, that this type of saving data is not persistent. If you're activity is removed for the stack the state will be lost too. As @CapDroid mentioned this method is callded before the activity is paused.

**EDIT**
I would also recommend you to read the [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle) paragraph in the Activity documentation.

Comment: Hmm, if I save the data onPause function and call it when onResume function. What's different?

Comment: The difference is that with `super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Android will do all the heavy lifting for you. But if you need a more persistent type of saving data, then you will actually need something else (like a database, or shared preferences). An here it's up to you. The `Bundle` approach is for non-critical data, like the view's state, or some simple flag.

Comment: Another question, if I omit the super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), will it increase the memory?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What you mean by "increase the memory"?

Comment: I meant that if I omit the super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), will it affect on the memory and cause crash because of OutOfMemory?

Comment: No, it should not. This has nothing to do with the memory heap that is     allocated for you app.

Comment: That's all I want to know. Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

**onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)** is call before your activity going in `pause` mode. we can store any info in bundle so we can get that info from bundle in some case like as Orientation Change.

Below is simple example for how to use onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

   outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
     Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState .getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

**Note:** Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state

If you don't call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` then default method will not call. so you may be lost your data when your device has low memory and your activity going to be destory. When again it will be come in `OnCreate` your all view be create again..

For more information [Click here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: This is a nice post, but doesn't answer the question asked. How do these answers get upvotes?

Comment: Well, the main question I want to ask is what issue can cause if I omit the super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState). Can you explain me more?

Answer (score 0):

By not calling through to the super implementation of `onSaveInstanceState`, you are not allowing the Activity (or Fragment) to save its instance state.

This includes any transient state which hasn't yet been persisted into some other type of data storage.

For example, if you have an `EditText` view where the user types a long paragraph, if the user switches to another application and then back to yours, the state of the `EditText` (the text that the user has entered) could potentially be lost if your Activity is reclaimed by the system for memory reasons (which happens a lot in real use scenarios).

In other words, call `super.onSaveInstanceState` or you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Well, if I save the data on the onPause function and call it on the onResume. Do I need to use the super.onSaveInstanceState anymore?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` the default implementation saves the state of all your `View`s.

If you don't call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` then if your application is killed when it is in the background, your `View`s will all be reinitialized (as if newly created) when the user returns to your application.

Comment: If I save the data to db (sqlite) in the onPause function and restore it in onResume function. Is it ok?

Comment: You can save your data in `onPause()` and restore it in `onResume()`. Then you shouldn't implement `onSaveInstanceState()` at all. If you override `onSaveInstanceState()` make sure you call through to `super.onSaveInstanceState()` so that the default implementation will run. Otherwise your `View` state won't get properly restored.